# How to get json from REST API using java 8

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

As per my(a newbie's) understanding to get the json data from REST API could be done using jersey or httpClient. Is there any other way out?

Below is the json, I'm trying to get from external REST API:

```
{
  
  "myObject" : [ {
    "key" : {
      "srcSys" : "REPO_1",
      "srcSysRef" : "20200909_1911_1"
    },
    "productData" : {
      "id" : null,
      "number" : null,
      "isn" : null,
      "productId" : null,
      "productAdditionalData" : {
        "assetClassTree" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
        "description" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
        "productTypeData" : {
          "productType" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
          "productGroup" : "UNCLASSIFIED"
        }
      }
    },
    "state" : "OPEN",
    "type" : "01"
  }, {
    "key" : {
      "srcSys" : "REPO_2",
      "srcSysRef" : "20200403_3892_1"
    },
    "productData" : {
      "id" : "1",
      "number" : "11",
      "isn" : "null",
      "productId" : 1234,
      "productAdditionalData" : {
        "assetClassTree" : "xyz",
        "description" : "abc",
        "productTypeData" : {
          "productType" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
          "productGroup" : "UNCLASSIFIED"
        }
      }
    },
    "state" : "OPEN",
    "tradAcctType" : "01"
  } ]
  }
```

This API uses SSO authentication.

I've tried using jersey as below:

```
public <P> List<P> getAll(String resourcePath, GenericType<List<P>> entityType) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(this.baseUri, "target cannot be null");
        return this.client
                .target(this.baseUri)
                .path(resourcePath)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .cookie("mySSO", getCookie())
                .get()
                .readEntity(entityType);
    }
```

This expects json array as an output from REST API.But I'm not sure how to use it for json objects.

Can you please tell me, how do I get this in my java application.

Comment: You just pass your POJO class to `.readEntity()`. Do you know how map POJOs to JSON?

Comment: No, I'm don't know about it. Can you redirect me to the docs from where I should start.

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much :) This would be really helpful.

Comment: Thank me by posting an answer ;-)